# Wordpress not writing error.log

Tags: wp-debug

My local development WordPress install on ServerPress is not writing error logs. I made changes to my wp-config.php file to enable error log writing for WordPress, and also tried editing the php.ini file for xampplite to try and enable error tracking, But still, I could not get any logs going, so I reverted that to its original settings. My website currently displays

> There has been a critical error on your website.

in the front-end. I added the following code before the `define( 'DB_NAME', 'blahblahblah');` configuration:

```
/**Enable WP Debug */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

/** Enable WP Debug Log */
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

/**Display debug on HTML page*/
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Comment: Did you check for `debug.log` in the wp-content dir?

Comment: Yes, every time I made a change I looked in there.

Comment: The webserver process has to be able to write to `wp-content/debug.log`. Are the permissions set correctly on the file?

Comment: That's the only thing I was unsure of. I am using ServerPress on Windows 10, so I would imagine that runs as admin, so it should have permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You said you added the code in front of the file.
In the wp-config.php I'm working with there's this line towards the end:

`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

if your config file sets it to true `first` and then to `false` the problem could be that the last entry wins.

Answer (score 0):

I also had troubles getting the logging to work, checked the wordpress site and found it to recommend some plugins for logging.

I used the Query Monitor plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ and I finally got usable output from this.